# jQuery Easing in Chrome has a flicekring effect

Tags: jquery

I am using the following script for a smooth easing effect to navigate top/bottom within the same page. I got this successfully implemented in various browsers, but when the animation starts in Chrome, the page flickers. The page goes to the top when clicked in a flash and then allows the page to execute the animation.

Is there any possibility to get rid off the flickering effect in Chrome?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easing.1.3.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('a').bind('click',function(event){
                    var $anchor = $(this);

                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                    }, 1500,'easeInOutQuad');
                    /*
                    if you don't want to use the easing effects:
                    $('html, body').stop().animate({
                        scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
                    }, 1000);
                    */
                    event.preventDefault();
                });
            });
```

Comment: where is the script? and where is the page?

Comment: I will not be able to share the URL of the page. Apologize for not providing the code